# Base58Check Python Example

Tags: python, encoding, hash

I'm after a simple example of how to encode using the Base58Check library found here - I couldn't find any proper example of it:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/base58

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

Install:

- python setup.py build
- sudo python setup.py install

Then:

```
import base58
unencoded_string = "BEEFAFEEB"
encoded_string = base58.b58encode(unencoded_string)
```